# Perl regex is not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to pipe the output of a find command to a perl one-liner to replace a line that ends with `?>` with `RedefineForDocker::standardizeXmlmc()` but for some reason the value isn't being replaced. I've checked the output of the find command and it is performing as expected, and I've double checked my regex and it should match.

```
find . -name *.php -exec ggrep -Ezl 'class XmlMethodCall.*([?]>)$' {}  \; \
     | xargs perl -ewpn -i.bak2 \
     "s/[?]>\s*?$/RedefineForDocker::standardizeXmlmc()\n/gm"
```

I get no warnings and no indication that it isn't working, the backups are created, but the file remains unchanged. The list of matched files run from the find command is below.

```
./swsupport/clisupp/trending/services/data.helpers.php
./swsupport/clisupp/_bpmui/arch/service/data.helpers.php
./swsupport/clisupp/_bpmui/itsm/service/data.helpers.php
./swsupport/clisupp/_bpmui/itsm_default/service/data.helpers.php
./webclient_code/php/session.php
./webclient_code/service/storedquery/helpers.php
./php/_phpinclude/itsm/xmlmc/xmlmc.php
./php/_phpinclude/itsmf/xmlmc/xmlmc.php
./php/_phpinclude/itsm_default/xmlmc/xmlmc.php
```

Here is an example of one of the files it should match

https://regex101.com/r/BUoCif/1

Comment: Your Regex101 example and your `grep` criteria seem completely different.

Comment: `find . -name *.php` should be `find . -name '*.php'`

Comment: You can simplify your regex to `\?>\s*$`

Comment: Have you tried single quotes instead of double arround perl code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your `perl` command as this:

```
perl -i.bak2 -wpe 's/\?>\h*$/RedefineForDocker::standardizeXmlmc()\n/gm'
```

Order of command line option is important here.

Full pipeline should be like this:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec ggrep -PZzl '(?ms)class XmlMethodCall.*\?>\h*$' {} + |
xargs -0 perl -i.bak2 -wpe 's/\?>\h*$/RedefineForDocker::standardizeXmlmc()\n/gm'
```

Note use `-Z` option in `grep` and `-0` option in `xargs` to address issues with filenames with whitespaces etc.

Comment: Explanation: Perl's `e` option must be immediately followed by the program (i.e. `-e...`) or another argument containing the program (i.e. `-e ...`).

Comment: Note that the removal of `-n` wasn't necessary, but it's idomatic to omit it when `-p` is used because `-p` implies `-n`.

Comment: Note that the `/m` option is useless here.

Comment: Note that the more-commonly used `\s` would work just as well as `\h` here.